# How to reset protected accounts in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

Some of our Active Directory users were mistakenly added to Print Operators, which has converted their accounts to [protected accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory). The result of this, is that users who were delegated control of a particular OU aren't able to edit the attributes of the newly protected users.

I have removed the users from Print Operators and tried un-setting the `adminCount` attribute and allowed sufficient time for SDProp to run, but the attributes are still read-only for the users with delegated control.

Seems to me like the user accounts are still considered as protected accounts. How can I reset the account to a normal account? Is it just a case of editing the permissions for each user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the adminCount attribute (which you've done), AND you need to re-enable permissions inheritance on the object from the advanced security settings of the object.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Permissions cannot be delegated to an OU to modify accounts that are protected.

Once per hour, the SDProp process runs, and protected accounts have the permissions that are inherited from the OU *removed*, and the account has the ACLs that have been defined for protected accounts on the SDHolder object applied directly to the account.

The protected account needs to be reset from another highly privileged account (subject to the same SDProp process), to have the admincount set to zero and reset the permissions inheritance. (SDProp sets permissions but does not reset).